# Azure Cognitive Search on SharePoint - Get full file path or site name

Tags: sharepoint, azure-cognitive-search

I have deployed an Azure Cognitive Search Service to search through SharePoint files. The datasource is configured to use multiple different sites within the main sharepoint site.

*https://{domain}.sharepoint.com/sites/**{site-1}**/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx*
*https://{domain}.sharepoint.com/sites/**{site-2}**/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx*

The search works well and is able to return results from both sites, however the file path it returns comes as */drives/b!{redacted}/root:/{directory}/{filename}*

This corresponds to a file that is located at *https://{domain}.sharepoint.com/sites/{site-1}/Shared%20Documents/{directory}/{filename}*

This path is lacking the site name in the path and only shows *root:/*. I know the domain as it is setup when creating the dataset, I have the directory and filename, but without the actual site name, I am unable to construct a link to this file.

When constructing the index, this is the syntax used for file path:

```
    {
      "name": "metadata_spo_item_path",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": true,
      "filterable": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": "standard.lucene",
      "normalizer": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    }
```

Is there a way to get either the full path to the file or the site name in the search results?

Answer (score 2):

Can you try decoding **metadata_spo_item_path** value and assigning the value in a new field.  As I could not have sufficient permissions I could not proceed further.

Try to add below configuration in your indexer,

```
"fieldMappings" : [
 {
   "sourceFieldName" : "metadata_spo_item_path",
   "targetFieldName" : "Newfield",
   "mappingFunction" : {
     "name" : "urlDecode"
   }
 }]
```

Kindly refer [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-indexer-field-mappings?tabs=rest)